# Nested for-loop in Java giving an error

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm in a beginner class and my output should look like

```
25 20 15
26 21 16
27 22 17
28 23 18
```

This is my loop:

```
    for (int i = 25; i <= 28; i++){
        for (int a = i; a <= i-10; a -=5);{
            System.out.print(a);
        }
    System.out.println("");
    }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it, but it gives me an error message. Am I doing it right? Nested loops are really difficult for me...

Comment: `for (int a = i; a <= i-10; a -=5);{` this will never execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon on this line:

```
for (int a = i; a <= i-10; a -=5);{
```

Java thinks that the semicolon is the body of the loop.  Then `a` in the next block is out of scope, giving an error.

Additionally, the condition looks wrong on that `for` loop.  If you start `a` at `i`, then it will start out NOT less than or equal to `i - 10`.  Perhaps you meant

```
a >= i - 10
```

Comment: Thanks -- I don't have the error any more, but I guess the code is wrong because the output is completely blank. I'll try again...

Comment: @user2913362 I have amended my answer with I believe is wrong with the condition on the `a` for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have semicolon at the end of for cycle

```
for (int a = i; a <= i-10; a -=5);
```

Just remove it and here you go :

```
for (int a = i; a <= i-10; a -=5)
```

Also it is not fully functional, this code do output you want :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 25; i <= 28; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print((i - j*5) +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `a >= i - 10` in the middle of the second loop, not `<=`.  Also, remove that extra semicolon.